# SQL - Count using Ranges, but not exclusively

Tags: sql, oracle

So I was wondering, is there a way to count rows using ranges that aren't mutually exclusive? (Probably bad wording)

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
_ValueA_,_ValueB_,_ValueC_
   E1   |   1    |   0
   E2   |   6    |   1
   E3   |   12   |   4 
   E4   |   23   |   2

_ValueX_,_ValueY_
   X1   |    0
   X2   |    1 
   X3   |    4
   X4   |    2
```

And I want following result:

```
_VRange_,_ValueA_,_ValueB_,_ValueC_,_ValueX_
  <5    |   E1   |   1    |   0    |   X1
  <10   |   E1   |   1    |   0    |   X1
  <10   |   E2   |   6    |   1    |   X2
  <15   |   E1   |   1    |   0    |   X1
  <15   |   E2   |   6    |   1    |   X2
  <15   |   E3   |   12   |   4    |   X3
....
```

What I tried to do is use a nested `CASE WHEN` statement,

```
CASE WHEN ValueA < 5 THEN '<5' VRange ELSE
    CASE WHEN ValueA < 10 THEN '<10' ELSE
        -- Nested to 20
    END
END
```

but since that is exclusive (In the sense that, if your `ValueA` is above 10, it is also above 5 so it will never get into the <10 branch)

I also tried simply using a `UNION` select with according `WHERE` clauses, but that made the query slow to a crawl because it resulted in a set that was basically my table(s) cardinality times ten, also it was horribly long due to the join.

There's GOT to be a better way!

I'm on an Oracle DB, I'd like to avoid using oracle-specific syntax but I can if that provides a shorter query, I couldn't really find anything for my purposes though.

Any ideas?

Comment: put your largest values at the start of the case expression. Ie. `case when valuea > 20 then '>20' when valuea <10 then '<10' ... end`. Also, there is no need to nest your case expressions; you can have multiple when clauses! Oracle will stop when it reaches the first when clause that matches.

Comment: But that is exactly what I don't want, I want the repetition. I have a few different clauses ( <5, <10, <15, <20 ) and if I have a value like 3, I want the value to appear in my result 4 times each with the <5 in the `VRange` column. Also, I thought I had to nest my cases to get them into a single column?

Comment: in which case, you're going to have to define your ranges in a subquery and then join your table to those ranges, which is what Gordon shows in his answer.

Comment: Yes, I see, I didn't think about that at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to do this using `join`:

```
with t as (<your query here>),
     vals as (
      select 5 as lim, '< 5' as vrange from dual union all
      select 10 as lim, '< 10' as vrange from dual union all
      . . .
     )
select vals.vrange, t.*
from t join
     vals
     on t.ValueA < vals.lim;
```

Comment: Is there something missing between the right parenthesis of your with-as statement and the following select statement? Edit: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks a lot, sorry for the logic derp. I like to make things a lot more complicated for myself than I have to, sometimes.